# Gravatars are low-resolution

Tags: feature-request, gravatar

I just noticed that the avatars under posts are pixelated and blurry. Scaling down to double-resolution "retina" size would look much nicer. I have a feeling that this is a regression but don't have an old screenshot handy as evidence.

**Edit:** Site banners and the top navigation bar would be nice, too. Actually my own avatar in the nav bar is correctly scaled.

Comment: Ideally, of course, we'd have SVG gravatars.